# Return true when chunk is used iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, format, itext

I'm trying to bold my font by using chunk. But the special thing is that my label is written under the addcell within a datareader.

This is how i attempt to format my label within my datareader

```
table.AddCell(phrase.Add(new Chunk("test:", normalFont)) + dr[0].ToString());
```

This is the declaration to phrase and font type:

```
var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
var phrase = new Phrase();
```

And this is what is being displayed:

[image]

However before i attempt to format my label this is how it will look like

[image]

This is where i just directly add a label into my `table.AddCell`

```
table.AddCell(dr[0].ToString());
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, and I don't understand why your code compile. Can one add a string to a Phrase in C#? that shouldn't work, should it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie [Phrase.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Phrase.cs#l283) has an overload `public bool Add(String s)` which essentially adds a `new Chunk(s, font).`

Comment: OK, and what is the question? What does "my label is written under the addcell within a datareader" mean?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie what i meant was the words such as "test" was meant to be used as a label to say that the value displayed out for "test" is admin. Written under the addcell because i wrote the "label" which is "test" for example is in a addcell and within a datareader method. I used the datareader to read the data from the SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass

```
phrase.Add(new Chunk("test:", normalFont)) + dr[0].ToString()
```

to `table.AddCell`. The overload of `Phrase.Add` used here is declared as

```
public virtual new bool Add(IElement element)
```

> *(cf. [Phrase.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Phrase.cs#l297))*

Thus, `phrase.Add(new Chunk("test:", normalFont))` evaluates to the boolean value `true` and you have

```
true + dr[0].ToString()
```

Now the boolean is converted to a `string` itself:

```
"True" + dr[0].ToString()
```

In your case `dr[0].ToString()` seems to contain `"admin"`. So:

```
"True" + "admin"
```

Henceforth:

```
"Trueadmin"
```

And as this `string` is passed to `table.AddCell`, you get what you see.

[image: table cell with content "trueadmin"]

Instead you might want to do something along the lines of:

```
phrase.Add(new Chunk("test:", normalFont));
phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());
table.AddCell(phrase);
```

Comment: Good catch +1. I had no clue what the question was about due to the "my label is written under the addcell within a datareader".

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! i would appreciate if any of you knows how to solve this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952561/retrieve-decoded-binary-image-from-sql-and-insert-into-pdf-via-itextsharp-asp-ne