# Align the words in pdf using iTextSharp ASP.NET, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to align my words properly in my pdf as all of the words are clustered together. However, i'm adding my word format with a phrase. Hence, i googled some of the tutorial which doesn't seem to help.

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop\\New folder", filename), FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output);
        doc1.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;

        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
        doc1.Add(logo);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Font.BOLD);
        doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Official Report. Member Report ID : " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

        var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
        var phrase = new Phrase();


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, mr.citizenreport, pr.policereport, aor.officialreport from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[1].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Type Of Crime :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[2].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Location :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police ID :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[6].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[7].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[8].ToString());

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Official Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[9].ToString());

            table.AddCell(phrase);


        }

        dr.Close();
        doc1.Add(table);
```

However this is the end results when i run my pdf file.

[image]

I'm hoping each label will be aligned like this

**Full Name :** admin

**Contact :** 65498732

so on and so forth.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Chunk.NEWLINE:

```
        var phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :"));
        phrase.Add("Jame Tom");

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :"));
        phrase.Add("Jame Tom");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! i would appreciate if any of you knows how to solve this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952561/retrieve-decoded-binary-image-from-sql-and-insert-into-pdf-via-itextsharp-asp-ne