# Retrieve binary image data from SQL Server into pdf via iTextSharp ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf, itext

I'm trying to retrieve binary image data from my SQL server and export it into my pdf file by using the follow method

```
phrase.Add(new Chunk("Image :", normalFont));
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[0];
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
phrase.Add(bytes);

table.AddCell(phrase);
```

When i'm trying to display binary image data into my webapp using the above method, it works perfectly fine. Unfortunately when i want to export the image into my pdf file it doesn't work.

I have error like this on the phrase.Add method. I know i'm doing something wrong but i cant figure it out

[image]

Here is my entire back-end code for my PDF button.

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var doc1 = new Document();
        var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\apr12mpsip\\Desktop\\New folder", filename), FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, output);
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        doc1.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 585f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;

        var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
        doc1.Add(logo);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Font.BOLD);
        doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Official Report. Member Report ID : " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

        var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
        var phrase = new Phrase();


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, mr.citizenreport, pr.policereport, aor.officialreport, mr.image1 from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[1].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Type Of Crime :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[2].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Location :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police ID :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police Report Date Time :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[6].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[7].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Police Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[8].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Official Report :", normalFont));
            phrase.Add(dr[9].ToString());

            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Image :", normalFont));
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[0];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            phrase.Add(bytes);

            table.AddCell(phrase);


        }

        dr.Close();
        doc1.Add(table);
        doc1.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an image when creating a PDF with iTextSharp, you should use the `Image` class (from the `iTextSharp.text` namespace). This class has numerous static helper method `GetInstance` overloads which assist in creating an `Image` instance, cf. [the source](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Image.cs#l347). In your case most likely the overload with only one `byte[]` argument will do:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
[...]
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[10];
Image image = Image.GetInstance(bytes);
Chunk imageChunk = new Chunk(image, 0, 0);
phrase.Add(imageChunk);
```

Comment: you mean insert the codes inside the datareader? 

     phrase.Add(new Chunk("Image :", normalFont));
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[10];
                iTextSharp.text.Image image =    iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
                phrase.Add(image);

And i received this error

    insertion of illegal element 32

Comment: On which line do you get that? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: no sorry i dont. i can paste you a notepad file with the codes and error  right here 
http://www.filedropper.com/e32

Comment: this time i got an error  on the Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr[0];

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: Sorry, the `Image` is to be added to the `Phrase` wrapped inside a `Chunk`, not directly.

Comment: In your question you use `dr[0]` for the image, in your other comment you say `dr[10]`. So maybe you should use `dr[10]` here.

Comment: You're right. And it's working right now. However now i got one problem. I will post another question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: u miss something document.add(image);

Comment: *u miss something document.add(image);* @shal Why would the OP want to add the image to the document directly? After all it is added to `phrase` which in his code is added to a cell of a table which eventually is added to the document.

Comment: when i miss this statement no image appears to pdf document. I already use this technique so i consider never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I see two major problems in your code. There may be others, but let's start with these:

1. You have: `Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";` but you're creating a PDF, and your question shows that you're sending PDF to the browser, NOT an image. You need `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`.
2. I assume that `Byte[] bytes` represents an image. It beats me why you'd add these image bytes straight to a `Phrase` object. How on earth is the `Phrase` object supposed to know that these bytes should be converted to an `Image` object? You've skipped a couple of steps. First you need to create an `Image` object, then wrap that image inside a `Chunk`, then add that chunk to a `Phrase`.

For examples on creating images, please browse http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C10

If you want to know what wrapping images in chunks is about, please read the final pages of [chapter 2](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) of my book.